# Mysql insert and select query together convert to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I have a MySQL query that works great but when i try to convert it to MySQLI I can not get it to work:
WORKING SQL QUERY

```
<?php 
require_once( 'opendb.php' );
 $id = '105';
    // Start date
    $date = '2015-11-10';
    // End date
    $end_date = '2015-11-15';

    while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {

    $sql= "insert into test (Id,date,hours)
select  Id,
'".$date."' as date,
case dayname('".$date."')
    when 'Sunday' then Sun
    when 'Monday' then Mon
    when 'Tuesday' then Tue
    when 'Wednesday' then Wed
    when 'Thursday' then Thu
    when 'Friday' then Fri
    when 'Saturday' then Sat
else 0 end as hours
from emp where Id = '".$id."'";
mysql_query($sql);
    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    }?>
```

Not sure how to use Mysqli prepare statement when there is a select and insert in the same query.

MYSQLI NOT WORKING NOT SURE HOW TO GET IT TO WORK

```
  <?php 
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'xx', 'xx', 'xxx');
     $id = '105';
        // Start date
        $date = '2015-11-10';
        // End date
        $end_date = '2015-11-15';
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `test` (`Id`, `date`,`hours`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');    
        while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {      

    $sql= "select  Id,
    '".$date."' as date,
    case dayname('".$date."')
        when 'Sunday' then Sun
        when 'Monday' then Mon
        when 'Tuesday' then Tue
        when 'Wednesday' then Wed
        when 'Thursday' then Thu
        when 'Friday' then Fri
        when 'Saturday' then Sat
    else 0 end as '".$hours."'
    from emp where Id = 105 ";
    $mysqli->query($sql);;
          $stmt->bind_param('sss', $id , $date, $hours);
            $stmt->execute();
        $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
        }
    ?>
```

I understand how to use prepare in a insert statement but not when it is a insert and select statement together

The select statement is taking each day column the hours work on that day from table 1     eg id   Mon = 8   Tue = 6   Wed = 4    Thu= 0   Fri  = 6  Sat = 7     Sun = 0 and insert them into the test table

Comment: $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `test` (Id`,     missing  ` quote

Comment: it's just INSERT INTO test(id,date,hours) SELECT id, ? as date, case ...  Else o end as ? FROM ...  this should be what you prepare (before you begin the loop)

Comment: Not sure what you been i have 2 table the first table as empid then mon -sun as columns then each day as hours they work on that day I then loop each day in date range eg 2015/10/12 = mon so 8 hours is stored from table 1 because that what they work on Monday. the MySQL query works great a example would be good

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the select in your sql to do date formatting. You could do the date formatting in PHP, instead. That would make the mysqli insert a plain vanilla insert.

Comment: The select statement is taking each day column the hours work on that day    eg id   Mon = 8   Tue = 6   Wed = 4    Thu= 0   Fri  = 6  Sat = 7     Sun = 0 and insert them into the test table

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code.

1. You failed to read manual page on mysqli prepared statements.
2. As it is stated in the other answer, **you don't need neither prepared statements, nor mysqi, nor SQL here at all.**

ALL YOU NEED is to learn basic date operations

```
$date = strtotime('2015-11-10');
$end_date = strtotime('2015-11-15');
do {
    echo date('D',$date);
}while (($date = strtotime("+1 day",$date))  <= $end_date);
```

Comment: OK i am not just echo the day!!  I have 2 table table one has userid then 7 columns each with mon-sun, each employee works different hour on each day so the query takes lets say 2015-11-10 which is a Tuesday gets the hours worked  on Tuesday for that employee  which is 8 then inserts the userid   date  and hours into  test table database...